# Open the Settings app?

Tags: iphone, settings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Opening the Settings app from another app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655674/opening-the-settings-app-from-another-app)

Can i open the iPhone's Default Settings App from my Application?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this on iOS 5.0 and later:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs://"]];
```

Comment: Does not work in iOS 5.1 and later.

Comment: This only works on iOS 5.0, not later.